# Remove a DataRow in a DataTable that contains no numeric values

Tags: c#, datatables, datarow

I want to be able remove DataRows in a DataTable that contain null values for arrays containing no numeric data.

Trying to modify the code below which transposes the DataTable for use by Google Visualisation API:

```
private DataTable TransposeOpiate(DataTable inputTable)
{
    DataTable outputTable = new DataTable();

    // Add columns by looping rows

    // Header row's first column is same as in inputTable
    outputTable.Columns.Add(inputTable.Columns[0].ColumnName.ToString());

    // Header row's second column onwards, 'inputTable's first column taken
    foreach (DataRow inRow in inputTable.Rows)
    {
        string newColName = inRow[0].ToString();
        outputTable.Columns.Add(newColName);
    }

    // Add rows by looping columns        
    for (int rCount = 1; rCount <= inputTable.Columns.Count - 1; rCount++)
    {
        DataRow newRow = outputTable.NewRow();

        // First column is inputTable's Header row's second column
        newRow[0] = inputTable.Columns[rCount].ColumnName.ToString();
        for (int cCount = 0; cCount <= inputTable.Rows.Count - 1; cCount++)
        {
            string colValue = inputTable.Rows[cCount][rCount].ToString();
            newRow[cCount + 1] = colValue;
        }

        outputTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
    }

    return outputTable;
}
```

For example in the intellisense output shown below the row for improved, where the values after contain no data (this would normally be numeric values) instead contains empty indexes:

[image]

I need to be able to delete these rows if they are in the above format, how can I modify my code to perform this?

Comment: Not very sure what is being asked but can't you check for a null or an empty value

Comment: I usually just create a new instance of the table : DataTable dt1 = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => add filter here).CopyToDataTable();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not set a condition which prevents adding the row if all the row cells have a null value?

```
if (newRow.ItemArray.Any(x => x != null))
{
    outputTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
}
```

If you need to check for columns as well, do this right before returning `outputTable`

```
for (int col = outputTable.Columns.Count - 1; col >= 0; col--)
{
    bool toDelete = true;

    for (int row = 0; row < outputTable.Rows.Count; row++)
    {
        if (outputTable.Rows[row][col] != null)
        {
            toDelete = false;
        }
    }

    if (toDelete)
    {
        outputTable.Columns.RemoveAt(col);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with something like this (comments are in code):

```
private void CheckColumns()
{
    //table which we want to check
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    //add column definition - first column will be string, other two are int columns
    table.Columns.Add("string column", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("int column 1", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("int column 2", typeof(int));

    //add data - in this example rows "abc" and "ghi" are valid because they have at least one numeric column
    table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "abc", 1, 2 });
    table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "def", null, null });
    table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "ghi", null, 2 });
    table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "jkl", null, null });

    //filter rows in a way, using Linq, that rows are filtered where at least one column has numeric value
    var validRows = table.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.ItemArray.Any(c => IsNumeric(c))).ToList();
}

//this is helper method that code will call for each value in each row
private bool IsNumeric(object value)
{
    int outputValue;
    return int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out outputValue);
}
```

If you'll have decimal values, then you should une `decimal.TyrParse` in `IsNumeric` method.

If you need to be sure that all columns except first one have numeric values, you can do it like this (skipping first value from each row and checking if all other values are numeric)...

```
var validRows = table.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.ItemArray.Skip(1).All(c => IsNumeric(c))).ToList();
```

once you have those 'valid' rows, you can write that data into another table or do whatever you need to do with those data...

Instead of `.ToList()` you can use `.CopyToDataTable()` method so you'll get new DataTable with those 'valid' rows. For example:

```
DataTable newDataTable = table.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.ItemArray.Skip(1).All(c => IsNumeric(c))).CopyToDataTable();
```